# Is there a way to exclude questions with certain tags from "Review" tasks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When dealing with (in my case) questions that are Windows related, I have some of the worst luck trying to figure out what to do with them.  Sometimes I'll stare at it for 3-5 minutes, and have no idea what to do.  And I've had some cases of flagging things where I missed some distinction (because windows all blurs together for me) that makes some question sufficiently different from or another to not be a duplicate, or it deals in some arcane bit of tech that I don't use, so trying to determine the validity of a question or answer is (almost) entirely speculation on my part.

In many cases, it would be far better for me to not even see things tagged with Windows or Windows-related tags, because I'm about roughly as likely to miss-diagnose a question or answer as to provide helpful feedback.

Is there any way to exclude such-tagged questions from coming up while reviewing questions/answers?  If not, is there any way that it could be included?

Some may say, "Then quit reviewing things."  Which, I guess has some validity, but in general, things that aren't Windows, I've got a pretty good hit-rate on providing useful feedback.  And I like to be helpful when I can.  So, I'm left wondering what to do.

Comment: Maybe for it being a network wide suggestion, we should suggest it on MSO as well?

Comment: I'm willing for the question to be migrated if that is appropriate.

Comment: couldn't you just skip them? I do that whenever there's anything I don't get

Comment: If you just "skip" them, don't they come right back after you finish with all the others, and you hit the "review" link again?

Comment: @killermist once you skip they don't come back

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the only way to affect the selection of questions to review is through the **filter** functionality.

[image]

However, there is no way to *exclude* a specific tag.

Comment: I think you're thinking about moderator actions, where I'm just talking about "simple user" review functions.  Though, maybe I should look further into this filtering function.  But, I suspect we're talking about 2 different things.

Comment: @killermist: It should take you 3 clicks to get there. Should be pretty easy to find out.

Comment: I did look.  It would appear that is a white-list kind of thing, which  would work opposite of the blacklist kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @killermist: I know, that's why I put it in the answer.